# How to mock REST Services?

Tags: spring, testing, rest, mocking, mule

I have a maven/mule/spring development environment that I build REST services within.  I also have a series of TestNG tests to validate these services.  I also want the ability to alter the responses from the services, either returning specific information or throw an exception.  This was I can automatically test broader behaviours of the services.  I figured that mocking the services would be the best approach, but I cannot find any good information on how to mock a REST service.

Is there any material I can review on how to mock a REST web service?

--Update---

I thought I would add an example to make the problem more concrete.  If I have the following setup:

```
testA calls serviceA, which then calls serviceB
```

If serviceA should return a web exception to testA if serviceB responds with an error, I would like to inject a mockedServiceB in to the system for the test where mockedServiceB always returns an error:

```
testA calls serviceA, which then calls mockedServiceB (which always returns an error to serviceA)
```

Comment: For small-scale manual mockup, you can use static files and .htaccess on a webserver.

Comment: That does not feel like the right approach.  I don't think I should have to alter a server resource just to improve a test.  I would rather, if possible, contain my test material to my test suites.  Perhaps using a WSDL or WADL to create test material.

Comment: As I said, small-scale manual mockup. It's not scalable by any means, but if you just need to make sure that your app responds correctly to `400`+ level errors and that it can successfully receive data from `GET` then it will work just fine. There's a reason I didn't consider that comment an answer to your question.

Comment: No worries.  Thank-you for clarifying.

Comment: I realized that my first comment above is misleading.  I added some information in question to clarify my position.

Comment: Curious: how are your serviceA -> serviceB calls wired up in Mule?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking I would fragment my Mule configuration to have one service per fragment then load real service A fragment and a test service B fragment at test time. Test service B would use the Mule test:component to simulate good or bad returns.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and wrote a small lib for mocking REST services: https://github.com/mkotsur/restito.
You can give it a try.